# Setting up VPN client: L2TP with IPsec

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, l2tp

I've got to connect to vpn server. It works on Windows, but in Ubuntu 10.04 not. Number of options is confusing for me. There is the input that I have:

- IP Address of VPN
- Pre-shared key to authenticate
- Information that MS-CHAPv2 is used
- Login and Password to VPN

I was trying to achive that with `network manager` and with `L2TP IPsec VPN Manager 1.0.9` but both failed. There is some logged information from `L2TP IPsec VPN Manager 1.0.9`:

```
Nov 09 15:21:46.854 ipsec_setup: Stopping Openswan IPsec...
Nov 09 15:21:48.088 Stopping xl2tpd: xl2tpd.
Nov 09 15:21:48.132 ipsec_setup: Starting Openswan IPsec U2.6.23/K2.6.32-49-generic...
Nov 09 15:21:48.308 ipsec__plutorun: Starting Pluto subsystem...
Nov 09 15:21:48.318 ipsec__plutorun: adjusting ipsec.d to /etc/ipsec.d
Nov 09 15:21:48.338 ipsec__plutorun: 002 added connection description "my_vpn_name"
Nov 09 15:21:48.348 ipsec__plutorun: 003 NAT-Traversal: Trying new style NAT-T
Nov 09 15:21:48.348 ipsec__plutorun: 003 NAT-Traversal: ESPINUDP(1) setup failed for new style NAT-T family IPv4 (errno=19)
Nov 09 15:21:48.349 ipsec__plutorun: 003 NAT-Traversal: Trying old style NAT-T
Nov 09 15:21:48.994 104 "my_vpn_name" #1: STATE_MAIN_I1: initiate
Nov 09 15:21:48.994 003 "my_vpn_name" #1: received Vendor ID payload [RFC 3947] method set to=109 
Nov 09 15:21:48.994 003 "my_vpn_name" #1: received Vendor ID payload [Dead Peer Detection]
Nov 09 15:21:48.994 106 "my_vpn_name" #1: STATE_MAIN_I2: sent MI2, expecting MR2
Nov 09 15:21:48.994 003 "my_vpn_name" #1: NAT-Traversal: Result using RFC 3947 (NAT-Traversal): i am NATed
Nov 09 15:21:48.994 108 "my_vpn_name" #1: STATE_MAIN_I3: sent MI3, expecting MR3
Nov 09 15:21:48.994 004 "my_vpn_name" #1: STATE_MAIN_I4: ISAKMP SA established {auth=OAKLEY_PRESHARED_KEY cipher=oakley_3des_cbc_192 prf=oakley_sha group=modp1024}
Nov 09 15:21:48.995 117 "my_vpn_name" #2: STATE_QUICK_I1: initiate
Nov 09 15:21:48.995 004 "my_vpn_name" #2: STATE_QUICK_I2: sent QI2, IPsec SA established transport mode {ESP=>0x0c96795d <0x483e1a42 xfrm=AES_128-HMAC_SHA1 NATOA=none NATD=none DPD=none}
Nov 09 15:21:49.996 [ERROR  210]   Failed to open l2tp control file 'c my_vpn_name'
```

and from `syslog`:

```
Nov  9 15:21:46 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Opening client connection
Nov  9 15:21:46 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command ipsec setup stop
Nov  9 15:21:46 o99 ipsec_setup: Stopping Openswan IPsec...
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 kernel: [ 4350.245171] NET: Unregistered protocol family 15
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 ipsec_setup: ...Openswan IPsec stopped
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command ipsec setup stop finished with exit code 0
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command invoke-rc.d xl2tpd stop
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command invoke-rc.d xl2tpd stop finished with exit code 0
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Opening client connection
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Closing client connection
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command ipsec setup start
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 kernel: [ 4350.312483] NET: Registered protocol family 15
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 ipsec_setup: Starting Openswan IPsec U2.6.23/K2.6.32-49-generic...
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 ipsec_setup: Using NETKEY(XFRM) stack
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 kernel: [ 4350.410774] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 kernel: [ 4350.413601] padlock: VIA PadLock not detected.
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 kernel: [ 4350.427311] padlock: VIA PadLock Hash Engine not detected.
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 kernel: [ 4350.441533] padlock: VIA PadLock not detected.
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 ipsec_setup: ...Openswan IPsec started
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command ipsec setup start finished with exit code 0
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command invoke-rc.d xl2tpd start
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 ipsec__plutorun: adjusting ipsec.d to /etc/ipsec.d
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 pluto: adjusting ipsec.d to /etc/ipsec.d
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command invoke-rc.d xl2tpd start finished with exit code 0
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 ipsec__plutorun: 002 added connection description "my_vpn_name"
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command ipsec auto --ready
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 ipsec__plutorun: 003 NAT-Traversal: Trying new style NAT-T
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 ipsec__plutorun: 003 NAT-Traversal: ESPINUDP(1) setup failed for new style NAT-T family IPv4 (errno=19)
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 ipsec__plutorun: 003 NAT-Traversal: Trying old style NAT-T
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command ipsec auto --ready finished with exit code 0
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Executing command ipsec auto --up my_vpn_name
Nov  9 15:21:48 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Command ipsec auto --up my_vpn_name finished with exit code 0
Nov  9 15:21:49 o99 L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon: Closing client connection
```

Can anyone tell me something more about that? Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are hitting the bug in xl2tpd. Please check this link https://answers.launchpad.net/l2tp-ipsec-vpn/+question/169775